Navigate from compose activity to a fragment of another activity
I am migrating an application from activities/fragments to compose screens. This means that I have to use the interop approach in the interim. I tried setting up navigation using Kotlin DSL. The docs seem to cover a lot of ground, however I was not able to find a way for my scenario:
I have a new activity that hosts fragments with compose screens. I also inherited a legacy activity that is a host to many fragments. This legacy activity also hosts an app bar. In order to navigate from a new compose screen to a legacy screen seamlessly, I need to navigate to the legacy activity and then load up the specific fragment. I could not find how to do this in the docs. I thought that this would have to happen in the nav graph builder or a custom navigation, but I did not find any API that would allow that in their respective builders. Navigating to just a fragment means I lose the app bar, and navigating to just the host activity means we're not really getting to where we want.
I can certainly think of some hacks where I pass args to the activity destination, and then load fragments based on those, but that really feels rather dirty. Is there a cleaner, more conventional way?
Edit: looks like deep links would allow me to set up navigation to exactly where I want to go. However I still don't see how it would load another activity and then a fragment within it.
Pseudocode:
// LegacyActivity.java
public class LegacyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    setSupportActionBar()
    setUpDrawerLayout()
    // lots of other legacy implementation code
}


// NewActivityThatWillEventuallyReplaceLegacyActivity.kt
class NewActivityThatWillEventuallyReplaceLegacyActivity : FragmentActivity() {
    val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
    val navController = navHostFragment.navController
    navController.graph = navController.createGraph(
        startDestination = "newComposeFragment"
    ) {
        fragment<NewComposeFragment>("newComposeFragment")
        // How to set up a destination that would load LegacyFragment inside of LegacyActivity?
    }
}

// NewComposeFragment.kt
class NewComposeFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
    return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
         setContent {
             SomeComposeScreen()
         }
    }
}

// LegacyFragment.kt
class LegacyFragment : Fragment() {
    // Legacy implementation. This fragment is loaded into the LegacyActivity. This is the destination, but I need the app bar from the LegacyActivity displayed as well.
    // This will eventually be migrated to a compose screen.
}


Have you looked at the new navigation-fragment-compose artifact in Navigation 2.8.0-alpha07? It allows you to have composable destinations in your navigation XML file alongside your fragment destinations, all in one activity.

Thanks @ianhanniballake. That's handy, but I'm not sure how it applies to my scenario. I need to navigate between two activities - one that supports compose fragments and one that is already set up for legacy, non-compose fragments. And I need to be able to specify which legacy fragments should be displayed in the second activity. I am not really tied to XML, as legacy nav was originally set up in code via fragment transactions api, so unless that gives me some significant advantage why would I not stick with the Kotlin DSL?

Sorry, I've edited my post to add a bit more clarity.

It is unclear why you are using two activities at all or why that was chosen as an interop technique - that doc you linked absolutely never, ever suggests you should be using separate activities as part of a migration. Can you explain why you chose that approach?

I've added some pseudocode to better demonstrate my case. Basically there is a lot of legacy content that is already set up the way it is, and I still need to be able to access it from new compose screens. I am trying make 0 to minimal changes to the LegacyActivity, although I realize I will likely have to set up the navigation component there in the interim. Reimplementing code from LegacyActivity in the new activity is too much overhead at this time, so I am trying to leverage what I already have. Hope that makes it clearer.
